# Template group not appearing in file system

Tags: templates, 404

I've created a template group called temp, and inside this template group I've create a few templates. But when I try to view the templates I get a 404 error. I've checked my files and the template.group folder is not being created. My permissions seem to be fine (every folder up to the root is 755). Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like an .htaccess problem to me. What do you have in there? Are you removing the index.php file? What happens when you do youdomainname.com/index.php/temp/templatename ? Does the template appear then?

Answer (score 2):

In template global preferences set "allow templates to be saved as files". Then edit a template from the control panel template manager, and check the checkbox to save the template as file.

When you click save a notice should appear (top of window) that the file is saved. If EE is somehow not able to save the file, it will show a notice. Most of the times this is due to file permissions and/or file ownership.

*Figure 1. Notice when unable to save template as file*

[image: example: cannot save template as file]

**Additional info**

- Inside the template directory, the basic structure is
  `default_site/groupname.group/template_name.html`
- Try saving a file from the template manager first
  and verify and follow the directory structure from there.